# Execute XSLT to create HTML page to display XML items

Tags: javascript, xml, templates, xslt

Experts:

Input XML:

```
<Users>
      <User>
            <Name>1</Name>
            <Phrase>User 1 Code</Phrase>
            <Value>1111</Value>
      </User>
      <User>
            <Name>2</Name>
            <Phrase>User 2 Code</Phrase>
            <Value>2222</Value>
      </User> 
</Users>
```

Question:

How can I have a HTML page that upon click of a button on the page, would run a xslt code that will execute to fetch all the "Value" elements' values and popup an alert message with those values?

Comment: You don't need XSLT in this case , XSLT is for XML->HTML translation

Comment: Hello Cherniv - Thanks for your response although I should also point out my utter lack of knowledge in XML and XSLT. If I don't need XSLT how else can I traverse to the particular element - in this case,  'Value' - without XSLT? Assuming it can also be achieved without using XSLT, how does one go about doing it in XSLT?

Comment: You can use jQuery for this purpose , have a look at this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/0PVCHm?p=preview